# Discord.js backup json file

Tags: discord.js, fs

How can i backup json file every 5 mins to protect it from corruption using Discord.js?
I am using fs node plugin and i want to use this file for storing prefixies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fs.copyFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback) to duplicate the JSON file and [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to do so every 5 minutes.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

setInterval(() => {
  fs.copyFile(
    'path/to/file.json',
    'path/to/backup.json',
    (err) => console.error
  );
}, 1000 * 60 * 5);
// 1000 ms * 60 sec * 5 min
```

However, it would be a *much* better idea to implement and use a proper database. You'll thank yourself later.